# How to prevent child Views overlapping their parent ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The top of my `ScrollView` and it's child `Image` (`img1`) are below.

I dragged the image down slightly so you can see that it's overlapping the edges of the `ScrollView` corners.

[image]

Here is my View:

```
struct Match: View {
    @State var img1: Image? = nil
    @State var img2: Image? = nil
    @State var img3: Image? = nil
    @State var number: Text = Text("25")
    let storage = Storages()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            number.font(.system(size: 25))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading){
                    img1?.resizable().scaledToFit()
                        Text("Text")
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 35, bottom: 55, trailing: 0))
                            
                        Text("500")
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 35, bottom: 20, trailing: 0))
                }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                img2?.resizable().scaledToFit()
                img3?.resizable().scaledToFit()
            }.background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("LightBlack70%"))
            ).frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
            
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
```

How do I prevent the image overlapping the `ScrollView`? The `ScrollView` has a `cornerRadius: 15`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add clip shape (because it is not ScrollView but your custom added background has rounded corners), like

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
 
 // .. content here

}.background(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
        .foregroundColor(Color("LightBlack70%"))
).clipShape(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
).frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
```